# Are there any problems we have O(1) algorithms for that we originally didn't?

Tags: complexity-theory

Are there any problems which we now have constant time algorithms for, but originally had more complicated algorithms?

Comment: Arguably, the sum of integers `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n`. There's an [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) about it. This has a constant time solution, yet you may mistakenly create an O(n) solution.

Comment: @Obicere That's a great example of what I'm looking for--something that has a naive algorithm that's inefficient but where a constant time solution exists.

Comment: You could even consider a hashmap to be another example. The naive solution for lookup would be to iterate every element, checking for equality. Whereas utilizing a hashing function can reduce this to (near) constant time.

Comment: Even a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) would work. Most of the examples you'll find will be a mathematical series that ends up having a very simple solution.

Comment: Obscure example: before the [Binomial heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) was invented, [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants) insertions were `Θ(log n)` instead of `Θ(1)`.